# android:windowTranslucentStatus=true, android:fitsSystemWindows=true , gap above listView

Tags: android, android-layout

I need translucent status bar. So I use flag in styles.xml.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
             android:background="#ffffff"
             android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

            <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="Test"/>                         

               <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

When I click on EditText the soft keyboard overlap the editText. So I use flag "android:fitsSystemWindows=true "to fix this. OK. 
But as result above on listView (between "tool_bar" and "containerCenter) has gap with height equal to height of status bar.
How I can remove this gap?

Here is attach:
[image]

If  I move the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the top-most LinearLayout
the gap is gone BUT statusbar not translucent anymore. See attachment#2
[image]